# Inequalities involving summation

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

I have been struggling with the following math problem for quite a while without any real progress:

Let $\ n \in \mathbb N$

Show  that $$\frac{127}{7}(n-1)^7 \le \sum_{n=k}^{2n-1}  k^6 \le \frac{127}{7}n^7.$$

I would like to know how to approach the problem above and also how to approach these kinds of problems in general since I barely have any previous experience with them. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Induction might work ? or area under a graph approximated by rectangles

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=x^6$ is increasing, so by considering the area under the curve
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{n-1}^{2(n-1)} k^6 dk \leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}  k^6 \leq \int_{n}^{2n} k^6 dk. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it suffices to note that $y= x^6$ is *increasing,* the convexity is not needed.

Comment: @MartinR That's right ... I wish I had said that. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

The right inequality you can prove by induction, for which prove that:
$$\frac{127n^7}{7}+(n+1)^6\leq\frac{127(n+1)^7}{7}$$ and